# Phpqatools install failed

Tags: php, configuration

Recently i tried to install phpqatools, but when I try:

> > sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools

I receive the message:

> > No releases available for package "pear.phpqatools.org/phpqatools"
> >     install failed

Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this same problem.

Apparently phpqatools decided to no longer offer a pear channel. You need to install the tools through composer now.

Or you may have this problem : http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=20203

Comment: I've solved my problem installing the tools through composer.